# How to get text ranges based on fonts

Tags: ms-word, office-js, openxml

I have a paragraph that has multiple fonts applied. There are a number of ranges because of that. Is there a way (without working with the OOXML directly) to get these ranges, their fonts, and their text? Here is an example OOXML snippet I'm talking about:

```
      <w:p w:rsidR="00301FAD" w:rsidRDefault="00301FAD">
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001D4040">
          <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:bCs/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Spam</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001D4040">
          <w:rPr>
            <w:b/>
            <w:bCs/>
            <w:i/>
            <w:iCs/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>and</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
        </w:r>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="001D4040">
          <w:rPr>
            <w:i/>
            <w:iCs/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>eggs</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
```

The paragraph text in Word looks like this:

> **Spam** ***and*** *eggs*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the paragraph class' split method which can split the paragraph into ranges based on a string. I used this function to print the font and the text of the example provided:

```
async function run() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const body = context.document.body;

    var par = body.paragraphs.getFirst();
    let words = par.split([" "]);
    let first_word = words.getFirst();
    first_word.load(["font", "text"]);
    await context.sync();

    console.log(f_word.font);
    console.log(f_word.text);
  });
}
```

One downside to this is that you can't differentiate between a word that has fonts like this: *Sp**a**m*, or like this: *S**p**am* since it will set the bold property to null both times.